# Useing k8s kompose convert results in unknown stuff

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher

I'm currently trying to migrate my deployment from docker-swarm to RKE/k8s but I'm running into issues where I'm not sure how to resolve those or how to bypass them.

my docker-compose.yml is about 700 lines long and contains about 15 containers.
if I trigger the cmd. "kompose convert" a lot of yaml files getting generated but also a lot of warnings where I'm unsure how to interpret those ...

For example:

- WARN Volume mount on the host "/glusterfs/system/logs/db/maxscale" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host
- WARN Volume mount on the host "/var/run/docker.sock" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host
- WARN Ignore pid in secrets for service: celery-beat
- WARN External secrets elastic_pwd is not currently supported - ignoring
- WARN External secrets redis_pwd is not currently supported - ignoring
- WARN node.role constraints in placement is not supported, only 'node.hostname', 'engine.labels.operatingsystem' and 'node.labels.xxx' (ex: node.labels.something == anything) is supported as a constraint

So my question is: Where should i start to fix things up and how to mitigate these issues?!
As you can already imagine I'm new to RKE/k8s

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd recommend reading through the Kubernetes documentation to understand some of the core concepts, especially Deployments and Services, and then feel free to completely rewrite the `kompose` output.  A couple of the things that are listed here (host volume mounts, sharing the Docker socket, container pid namespace sharing) don't really work in Kubernetes at all; others (Secrets, scheduling constraints) work differently in Kubernetes than in Docker Swarm.

Comment: Seems like a very heavy task to me, anyways thanks for your feedback